# How to shorten my Oracle Query which includes looking for data of same field?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a shorter way to write below query in Oracle:

```
select * from booknames where author = 'Doyle' or author ='Brown' or author = 'Martin' or author = 'Kafka';
```

I don't like the sound that I have to write field name (author) 4 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from booknames where author in ('Doyle', 'Brown', 'Martin', 'Kafka');
```

The rules that govern the use of the IN operator include the following:

- IN can be used with dates, numbers, or text expressions.
- The list of expressions must be enclosed in a set of parentheses.
- The list of expressions must be of the same datatype - or be similar enough
  that Oracle can perform automatic datatype conversion to make them all
  the same.
- The list can include anywhere from one expression to several, each separated
  by commas.

Comment: To add to above answer, IN clause has a limit that you cannot use more than 1000 items in the list.

Comment: While all answers were same, you were quickest. Thanks. Thanks for explanation also.